# How to create a customized POJO class from XML file?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, pojo

I have an XML file which is like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements area="Login" page="Login" description="Description about the generated class">    
    <element key="USERNAMETEXTBOX" findBy="ID" id="username" tag="input" name="" text="" xPath="//*[@id='username']"/>     
    <element key="PASSWORDTEXTBOX" findBy="ID" id="password" tag="input" name="" text="" xPath="//*[@id='password']"/>
    <element key="LOGINBUTTON" findBy="XPATH" id="" tag="button" name="" text="" xPath="//input[@value='LOGIN']"/>
</elements>
```

Reading this XML file, I need to generate a POJO class which will look like this.

```
public class LoginPO extends CommonActionHelper{

    LoginBean loginBeanObj= new LoginBean();
    private WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(id="username")
    private WebElement USERNAME;

    @FindBy(id="password")
    private WebElement PASSWORD;

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@value='LOGIN']")
    private WebElement LOGIN;    
}
```

Basically, the `page` attribute of `elements` tag appended with the string "PO" should be the class name. The `key` attribute of `element` tag must be the member variables. Depending on the `findBy` attribute value (ID/XPATH), corresponding attribute must be added in the annotation `@FindBy()`

Please help!

Comment: You could try `apache velocity`

Comment: @RogerDwan is there a sample project or code that I can refer? It would be of great help.

Comment: [Show basic XML handling in a template : XML « Velocity « Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Velocity/ShowbasicXMLhandlinginatemplate.htm)
I found this which is not hard to understand for beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="elements"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elements">
public class <xsl:value-of select="@area"/>PO extends CommonActionHelper{
 <xsl:value-of select="@area"/>Bean <xsl:value-of select="translate(@area,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>BeanObj= new  <xsl:value-of select="@area"/>Bean();
private WebDriver driver;
<xsl:apply-templates select="element"/>
}
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="element[@findBy='ID']">
@FindBy(id="<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>")
private WebElement <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="variable"/>;
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element[@findBy='XPATH']">
@FindBy(xpath="<xsl:value-of select="@xPath"/>")
private WebElement <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="variable"/>;
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element" mode="variable">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="substring(@key, string-length(@key) - 6) ='TEXTBOX'"><xsl:value-of select="substring(@key,1,string-length(@key)-7)"/></xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="substring(@key, string-length(@key) - 5) ='BUTTON'"><xsl:value-of select="substring(@key,1,string-length(@key)-6)"/></xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise>!!<xsl:value-of select="@key"/></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

processing:

$ xsltproc transform.xsl input.xml

```
public class LoginPO extends CommonActionHelper{
 LoginBean loginBeanObj= new  LoginBean();
private WebDriver driver;

@FindBy(id="username")
private WebElement USERNAME;

@FindBy(id="password")
private WebElement PASSWORD;

@FindBy(xpath="//input[@value='LOGIN']")
private WebElement LOGIN;

}
```